# inserting data in temp table with read only database access

Tags: sql-server, import, excel

I only have read only access to my company's database (no chance of getting write) and want to import Excel data to a temp table, is this possible?

I can create temp tables tied to just my computer, but can't find a way other than inserting, is there a quicker way?

```
create table #tmp
(col1 int, col2 int)

insert into #tmp (col1, col2)
values(1,2)
```

I may be doing something wrong, but I don't have a local database that I can save tables to. I'm using the client version if that helps, I've been told I would need to pay for a license for write capability.

I'm trying to create a temp table because I only have read access to 1 server/database, is there another way to save? I'm looking to create a table from an Excel file and am having trouble using the data wizard because of my read only access.  Do I need write access to import any external data, even if being loaded to a temp table?

I have an Excel file that is going to be continuously updated that I want to run QC checks on and would much rather do it in SQL Server than Excel. I am the only one that needs to use it.

So first question is: Do I have my own database and just can't find it? Have tried local, the computer name, searching networks within SQL settings. When I try to import a file I have to connect to a database to do so and the only one I have is the read only.

Comment: If you need to load data into a database and need it to stay around, you would need write access to the database in question. If you just need to load the data and run a couple of queries, after which the data can be removed, then loading into a temp table could work for you. However, the amount of effort likely to be required is significant - I'd be trying to figure out if I could just do what I needed in Excel.

Comment: @Becky - regarding having a local database (and licensing), Sql 2016 Express is completely free and each database can be up to 10gb.  It works quite well with Excel using Import and Export capabilities.  It might help us if you could elaborate on WHY you think you need temp tables.  Explaining WHAT you are trying to do (instead of HOW you're trying to do it) may help us come up with some helpful solutions.

Comment: If you can create temp tables, you can write to `tempdb` - however, what you write there doesn't stick around. It's not like a temp folder - it's automatically removed when your connection is broken. As I've already said, and as @ScottHodgin repeated - add more information about what you are ultimately trying to accomplish, and we can provide better advice.

Comment: @Becky - it sounds like you just need to upload your data, run your checks, and then it's OK to remove the data. If so, see if you can create a regular table in `tempdb`; not `CREATE TABLE #myTable`, but `CREATE TABLE [tempdb].[myTable]`. If you can do that, you may be able to use the import wizard to upload your data to that table, and then run your checks. If that doesn't work, then installing a local copy of SQL Sever Express (giving you a server that's just yours), or asking your DBA team if there's a database you could use (or get created) for your process is your best bet.